# Evento com onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, javascript-eventos, onclick

Estou estilizando um 'input/campo de pesquisa' utilizando o **onclick** do *javascript*, consigo fazer 50% mas o restante estou quebrando a cabeça e não sei oque fazer.

Consegui fazer com que a caixa de entrada de texto para fazer a pesquisa apareça apenas quando clico no botão.

Mas preciso que ao clicar novamente no botão ou em qualquer outro canto da tela que não fosse no campo de pesquisa, automaticamente o campo de pesquisa se escondesse novamente, fizesse o mesmo efeito de exibir, porém ao contrário.

***Caixa de busca ex:***

[image: Escondido]

[image: Exibindo quando clicado!]

[image: Estado final quando clicado!]

Código:

```js
$('#imagembusca').click( function() {
  $("#busca").attr('style', 'width: 200px; transition: all 0.5s linear; border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0; padding:0 10px 0 30px;');
});
```

```css
#btbusca{
 max-width:250px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 0;
}
#imagembusca{
 background:#FF0004;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 20px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 padding: 7.5px 12px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
#imagembusca:hover{
 background: #B00002;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
#busca{
 background:#EEE;
 width: 0px;
 line-height:30px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 0 0 15px;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btbusca">
    <img src="https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/full/51-514569_dibujo-lupa-png-desenho-lupa-para-colorir.png" id="imagembusca" alt="buscar" />
    <input type="search" name="busca" id="busca" placeholder="Buscar">
   </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É mais fácil criar uma classe e usar `.toggleClass()` no click do botão. Por exemplo, você cria uma classe e coloca as propriedades do `style`:

```
#busca.aberto{
   width: 200px;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
   border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
   padding:0 10px 0 30px;
}
```

Cada vez que o botão for clicado irá abrir ou esconder o campo de busca.

E para esconder o campo ao clicar em qualquer lugar da tela, você usa o código abaixo para remover a classe do campo:

```
$(document).click(function(){
   $("#busca").removeClass('aberto');
});
```

Mas é preciso usar `event.stopPropagation()` no botão para não chamar o evento do `$(document)`:

```
$('#btbusca').click( function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Irá ficar desta forma:

```js
$('#imagembusca').click(function(){
   $("#busca").toggleClass('aberto');
});

$('#btbusca').click( function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).click(function(){
   $("#busca").removeClass('aberto');
});
```

```css
#btbusca{
 max-width:250px;
 height: 30px;
 padding: 0;
}
#imagembusca{
 background:#FF0004;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 border-radius: 20px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
 padding: 7.5px 12px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1;
}
#imagembusca:hover{
 background: #B00002;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
#busca{
 background:#EEE;
 width: 0px;
 line-height:30px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 0 0 0 15px;
 transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#busca.aberto{
   width: 200px;
   transition: all 0.5s linear;
   border-radius: 0 20px 20px 0;
   padding:0 10px 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btbusca">
   <img src="https://www.sccpre.cat/mypng/full/51-514569_dibujo-lupa-png-desenho-lupa-para-colorir.png" id="imagembusca" alt="buscar" />
   <input type="search" name="busca" id="busca" placeholder="Buscar">
</div>
```

Comment: Perfeito, exatamente oque estava precisando!

Answer (score 0):

use o método Onblur! assim você pega o evento ao tirar o foco do elemento!